# Count occurrences of each unique character

Tags: java, string

How to find the number of occurrence of every unique character in a String? You can use at most one loop. please post your solution, thanks.

Comment: Homework? Show us what you've done.

Comment: How to find what you've done already ? You can try to solve yourself first and then ask questions about problems you having. please post what you've done, thanks.

Comment: @Bert F my solution is similar to @zengr's, i was wondering if there is a better way, so i post the question here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since this sounds like a homework problem, let's try to go over how to solve this problem by hand. Once we do that, let's see how we can try to implement that in code.

**What needs to be done?**

Let's take the following string:

```
it is nice and sunny today.
```

In order to get a count of how many times each character appears in the above string, we should:

1. Iterate over each character of the string
2. Keep a tally of how many times each character in the string appears

**How would we actually try it?**

Doing this this by hand might be like this:

First, we find a new characeter `i`, so we could note that in a table and say that `i` appeared 1 time so far:

```
'i'  ->  1
```

Second, we find another new character `t`, so we could add that in the above table:

```
'i'  ->  1
't'  ->  1
```

Third, a space, and repeat again...

```
'i'  ->  1
't'  ->  1
' '  ->  1
```

Fourth, we encounter an `i` which happens to exist in the table already. So, we'll want to *retrieve* the existing count, and replace it with the existing count + 1:

```
'i'  ->  2
't'  ->  1
' '  ->  1
```

And so on.

**How to translate into code?**

Translating the above to code, we may write something like this:

- For every character in the string

  - Check to see if the character has already been encountered

    - If no, then remember the new character and say we encountered it once
    - If yes, then take the number of times it has been encountered, and increment it by one

For the implementation, as others have mentioned, using a loop and a `Map` could achieve what is needed.

The *loop* (such as a `for` or `while` loop) could be used to iterate over the characters in the string.

The *`Map`* (such as a `HashMap`) could be used to keep track of how many times a character has appeared. In this case, the *key* would be the character and the *value* would be the count for how many times the character appears.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! :) (ack, 15 character filter...)

Comment: Thank you for your kind words :)

Answer (score 5):

It's a homework, so cannot post the code, but here is one approach:

1. Iterate through the string, char  by char.
2. Put the char in a hashmap key and initialize its value to 1 (count). Now, if the char is encountered again, update the value (count+1). Else add the new char to key and again set its value (count=1)

Comment: Thanks :-), it's actually a interview question i answered few days ago, and your answer is similar to mine. i post the question here cause i want to know what is other programmer's thought on this.

Comment: I guess hashmap is the best possible answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here you go! I have done a rough program on Count occurrences of each unique character

public class CountUniqueChars{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map;        
        ArrayList<HashMap<Character, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<Character,Integer>>();
        int i;
        int x = 0;
        Boolean fire = false;

        String str = "Hello world";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\s", "").toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(str.length());

        for(i=0; i<str.length() ; i++){
            if(list.size() <= 0){
                map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
                map.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
                list.add(map);
            }else{              
                map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
                map.put(str.charAt(i), 1);

                fire = false;

                for (HashMap<Character, Integer> t : list){
                    if(t.containsKey(str.charAt(i)) == map.containsKey(str.charAt(i))){                 
                        x = list.indexOf(t);
                        fire = true;

                        map.put(str.charAt(i), t.get(str.charAt(i))+1);
                    }
                }               

                if(fire){
                    list.remove(x);
                }   

                list.add(map);

            }           
        }
        System.out.println(list);       
    }
}
```