# Number of occurarece of each char in a string

Tags: java, string, char, find-occurrences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count occurrences of each unique character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112111/count-occurrences-of-each-unique-character)

How can I get the number of occurrence of each char in a string? for example:

"stackoverflow":
s:1
t:1
a:1
c:1
k:1
o:2
v:1
e:1
r:1
f:1
l:1
o:1
w:1

Comment: and what have you googled? ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to the rescue!  I can't believe it, this is a java one-liner!

```
Multiset<Character> distintCharsAndCount = HashMultiset.create(
    Chars.asList("ssssssssstackoverflow".toCharArray())
);
```

Chars.asList helps us convert the string to a real collection of non-primitives.  MultiSets are the perfect structure for what you're after: it's a Set that keep distinct elements, but also keeps the number of occurances in the set.

Access it this way:

```
int sCount = distintCharsAndCount.count('s'); //sets it to 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Create HashMap with keys as a Character and Integer count as value.

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>()
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (hm.get(str.charAt(i))) {
        int temp = hm.get(str.charAt(i));
        hm.put(str.charAt(i), ++temp);
    } else {
        hm.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a map from character to count and iterating over the character array adding to the map or the count as you go along

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Character, Integer> chars = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);

    Integer count = chars.get(c);
    if (count == null) {
        chars.put(c, 1);
    } else {
        chars.put(c, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: As this is homework and the OP has not shown any effort would it not have been better to point him/her in the right direction as opposed to doing it for them?

Answer (score 1):

A simple but intuitive way that I have done this in the past is to cast the chars as ints and then just use an array. Using a Map is a better approach, but this sounds like a homework problem and using casting and an array is a bit more logical (imo) for a beginner.

```
int counts[] = new int[26];
String s = 'stackoverflow';
s = s.toLowerCase();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    int val = (int)(s.charAt(i)) - 97;
    counts[val]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the *string* and create a `Map<Character, Integer>` so that the *integer* (value in the map) represents how many times the character *c* (the key in the map) appears in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> count(String s) {
  Map<Character, Integer> result = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    Integer n = result.get(c);
    result.put(c, n == null ? 1 : n + 1);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "stackoverflow";

// desired output: s:1 t:1 a:1 c:1 k:1 o:2 v:1 e:1 r:1 f:1 l:1 o:1 w:1
Map<Character,Integer> counts = new HashMap<Character, Integer>
( Math.min(input.length(),Character.MAX_VALUE) / 2 );
char ch;
for (int i=0; i<input.length(); ++i)
{
  ch = input.charAt(i);
  if ( !counts.containsKey(ch)) { counts.put(ch,0); }
  counts.put(ch, counts.get(ch)+1 );
}

for (Map.Entry<Character,Integer> entry : counts.entrySet() )
{
  out.print( entry.getKey() );
  out.print( ":" );
  out.print( entry.getValue());
  out.print( " " );
}
```